# What does if (!window.Sys) mean in JS file?

Tags: javascript

I am debugging a JS file and have noticed this if statement:

```
if (!window.Sys)
```

A namespace is then initialized within this if conditional. My question is, what does this conditional test? There is not much information in the time I have taken to search for a meaningful answer in my scenario.

Comment: While it is a rudimentary question, it is written well and expressed previous research.. not too sure why the downvotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks up for the [Sys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397702(v=vs.100).aspx)-Namespace, whether it exists (or not).

This is a special namespace »[...]root namespace for ASP.NET AJAX«

Comment: Okay thanks! As a followup question: I have multiple JS files in my project and obviously this namespace is being initialized previous to this JS conditional. If I simply take out the conditional in my original question could this cause adverse affects? If so, is there a more optimal way of ensuring that this if statement runs at least once? Maybe I need to set window.Sys as undefined when I am done using it in my previous JS file?

Comment: To answer that properly, I need a lil' bit more Info... ;) So it is difficult to answer, what will happen.

Comment: Okay, a simpler question: How to set this Sys property to "empty" so that the if statement will run?

Comment: delete window.sys will delete the `sys` namespace from `window`. But beware of the side-effects

Comment: I don't want to delete it I want it to be set to empty again. I saw that when it was initialized, it is initialized to empty. Or, how would I create the window.Sys object again after deleting it?

Comment: window.sys={} will set it to an empty object.

Answer (score 2):

It tests if the `Sys` property of the object in the `window` variable evaluates as a false value.

This is usually shorthand for "Has something already defined `window.Sys`?"

Comment: Yea I get that I guess what I don't understand is exactly what this Sys property is. I cannot find much information on what this property actually does? @Quentin

Comment: `Sys` isn't a standard property provided by browsers. Presumably it is defined by the code you are debugging.